# Checkbox UIButton title not toggling when tapped

Tags: ios, uibutton

This code is for a tableViewController that lists tasks. When the UIButton is tapped, it's supposed to toggle the button's title from an empty string to a check mark. For some reason when I tap the button in the simulator, nothing happens and there are no errors showing in the console. Anyone know why it's not toggling? The reference code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks everybody!

Here's the UITableViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class LoLFirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tasks:[Task] = taskData

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }

    @IBAction func cancelToLoLFirstTableViewController(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    @IBAction func saveAddTask(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let AddTaskTableViewController = segue.source as? AddTaskTableViewController {

            if let task = AddTaskTableViewController.task {
                tasks.append(task)

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tasks.count-1, section: 0)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.task = task

        var rowChecked: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: tasks.count)

    if cell.accessoryView == nil {
                let cb = CheckButton()
                cb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                cell.accessoryView = cb
    }
            let cb = cell.accessoryView as! CheckButton
            cb.check(rowChecked[indexPath.row])

            return cell
    }

func buttonTapped(_ target:UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
            guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first else { return }
            let point = touch.location(in: self.tableView)
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
        var tappedItem = tasks[indexPath!.row] as Task
        tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed
        tasks[indexPath!.row] = tappedItem
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }
```

Here's the code for the UIButton:

```
import UIKit

class CheckButton : UIButton {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Georgia", size:10)
        self.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        self.check(false)
    }
    func check(_ yn:Bool) {
        self.setTitle(yn ? "✔" : "", for: .normal)
    }
    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? E.g. set a break point into the `check` function or add a log there. Is the method even called? If so, check (print) out the value of `yn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only every call `check` with `cb.check(rowChecked[indexPath.row])` and `rowChecked` is always an array of `[false, false, false, ...]`.

This should probably be `cb.check(tasks[indexPath.row].completed)` based on what you're doing in `buttonTapped`.

Comment: Ah, maybe I should make rowChecked update each time for the status of each item in indexPath?

Comment: Since rowChecked only exists in the function, there probably isn't a reason to keep it as `tasks` is already the record of truth.